# ¿Como hacer el efecto glow/borroso que esta implementando Youtube?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, bootstrap-5

En la ultima actualización de **Youtube**, ***Google*** ha metido un efecto **glow** detras de los video. Lo llama "cinematicmode" que coge el video en cuestión y crea el haz de luz ese mientras se va reproduciendo el video. Estoy con un proyecto de Boostrap5 intentando replicar el mismo formato que tiene youtube pero no sé como hacer. Desconozco si se puede hacer con JS o con CSS o con aluna librería externa.

El codigo en el que estoy trabajando :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 980px;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.b-example-divider {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    inset 0 0.125em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.b-example-vr {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -0.125em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

video {
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-tam {
  width: 220px;
  height: 140px;
}

.tit {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tit-video {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.descrip {
  color: white;
}

.img-logo {
  width: 30vh;
}
.img-user{
  width: 10vh;
}

.cont-descrip {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #dc3444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}




body{

  background: #304FFE;
} 

.form-control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}


.dashboard-header .navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  min-height: 60px;
}



.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #007bff;
}
.navbar-brand:hover{
  color: #007bff;
}
.navbar-right-top {}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item {
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item .nav-link {
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #82849f;
}


/* --  top-search-bar ---  */

.top-search-bar {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}


/* ------  Notification Dropdown --------  */

.notification {}

.notification-dropdown {
  min-width: 320px;
}

.notification-dropdown,
.connection-dropdown,
.nav-user-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.notification-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3d405c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fffffe;
}

.notification-list {}

.notification-list .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item.active {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #3d405c;
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
  border-color: #e1e1e7;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item-action:focus,
.list-group-item-action:hover {
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item:last-child {}

.notification-info {}

.notification-info .notification-date {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #71748d;
}

.notification .dropdown-toggle::after,
.connection .dropdown-toggle::after,
.nav-user .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border: none;
}

.notification-list-user-img {
  float: left;
}

.notification-list-user-block {
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.notification-list-user-name {
  color: #5969ff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.list-footer,
.conntection-footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #5969ff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.list-footer a,
.conntection-footer a {
  color: #fff;
}

.list-footer a:hover,
.conntection-footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.indicator {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ef172c;
  animation: .9s infinite beatHeart;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes beatHeart {
  0% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  25% {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  40% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  60% {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}


/* ------  Connection --------  */

.connection {}

.connection-dropdown {}

.connection-list {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.connection-item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 7px 4px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #3d405c;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.connection-item img {
  width: 32px;
}

.connection-item:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
}

.connection-item span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* ----- User Nav Dropdown -----*/

.nav-user {}

.nav-user-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 230px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-user-name {}

.nav-user-info {
  background-color: #5969ff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.nav-user-info .status {
  float: left;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav-user-dropdown {}

.nav-user-dropdown .dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 22px 15px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #686972;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 0.4;
}

.nav-user-dropdown .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
}

/*---- User icon sizes ---*/

.user-avatar-xxl {
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}

.user-avatar-xl {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.user-avatar-lg {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.user-avatar-md {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.user-avatar-sm {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

.user-avatar-xs {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}



.avatar {
  width: 2.25rem;
  height: 2.25rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F7F9FA;
  background: #F7F9FA;
  color: #fff;
}


.media-attachment div.avatar {
  border: none;
}

.avatar.bg-primary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.avatar.bg-primary i {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta
      name="author"
      content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors"
    />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>YouFlix</title>

    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.104.2" />


    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/checkout/"
    />

    <link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

  </head>

  <body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <main>


        <div class="py-5 text-center">
          <img
            class="d-block mx-auto mb-4 img-logo"
            src="Logo_negro_negro.webp"
            alt="YouFlix"
          />
          <h2 class="title">YouFlix</h2>
          <p class="lead text-light">Tu Web de Videos preferida</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-5">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
            <video class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" controls>
              <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <span
              class="tit-video badge bg-danger rounded-pill w-100 text-start"
              >TITULO DEL VIDEO</span
            >
            <div class="cont-descrip">
              <p class="descrip">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea,
                est? Error, enim. Esse, provident vitae aliquam, illum
                distinctio est quis quidem minus quisquam ullam quos, nisi neque
                necessitatibus voluptas dolorem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
            <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
              <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">TUS VIDEOS</span>
              <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">100</span>
            </h4>

            <ul class="list-group mb-5">
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light m-2">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
        <p class="mb-1">&copy; 2022–2023 YouFlix</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form-validation.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Esto seria el efecto en el movil]

No he encontrado ninguna del formato web.
Alguien me podría ayudar? Gracias de antemano. :)

Comment: Puedes usar ``backdrop-filter``: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo No me referia a un desenfoque en el video, me refiero a como puedo darle ese efecto glow detras del video? gracias